# Which CSS frameworks work perfectly with React?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, frameworks

I am currently working with ReactJS. I am looking for CSS framework which will go perfectly with react and help in excellent web designing.

Comment: Material UI is good, I also like the react version of Semantic UI

Comment: There are so many [CSS framework](https://github.com/troxler/awesome-css-frameworks) you can choose from. Each one has pros and cons, so we can not really help you selecting the "perfect" framework.

Answer (score 3):

React works particularly well with component-based styling, or *"CSS in JS"* solutions. They solve a lot of the common CSS problems, like styling conflicts.

While there's no clearly winner at the moment. [CSS Modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules) and [styled components](https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components) work perfectly with React and are easy to use.

By the way, you can use CSS Modules perfectly fine with CSS files (or even SASS), so you have the best of both worlds.

Check the [CSS Modules github repo](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules) for a good introduction. You just need to add a webpack loader, and import your style files in your JS code. Here's a [sample react app](https://github.com/ModusCreateOrg/budgeting-sample-app-webpack2) you can check, it uses CSS Modules + SASS.

Comment: ya, you are right. I am fan of react. I usually use foundation and bootstrap for styling purpose. But they are not fully ready for react. I will look into your suggestion, they may be helpful for my projects.

Comment: Agreed. If you need something more high level, you could Material-UI or React Toolbox.

I haven't used the last one yet, but it's build over CSS Modules.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I am not a fan of the *JS everything* approach. Sure, React might be designed with "CSS in JS" in mind, but the tooling that is available for working with ordinary stylesheets is simply much more mature (and better documented). So, I get the best of both worlds by combining React and JSX with CSS pre (and post) processors.

It is not as "revolutionary" as other options that are out there, but [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) is still a fantastic framework, which eases a lot of the pain of working with stylesheets.

A major benefit is that, thanks to imports, you are free to split up and compartmentalize your styles, but still end up with a single, dedicated css file per component. Thus, you avoid the oh so common problem of spaghetti stylesheets.